WebViewClient.onLoadResource method alternative in flutter_inappwebview?
Is There any alternative to WebViewClient.onLoadResource method in flutter?
I am looking for a function that will tell me what resources the web is loading in flutter.
I searched so far for an alternative but unable to find

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

flutter_inappwebview already have onLoadResource what kind of alternative you want. What did you really want to know when app was load ?

It is not there in flutter_inappwebview dependancy but you should give a try to https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter as it has more option and it might fullfil your requirement.

I appreciate your suggestion, but webview_flutter doesn't fully meet my requirements.
